# Uniqueness of a real number sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let ($x_n$) be a real number sequence.

I'm interested in sequence(s) ($y_n$) that we can construct based on ($x_n$) with the property that every term in it is smaller than only a finite number of terms in ($x_n$) .
In other words, i want a sequence ($y_n$) such that for every k, there are only a finite number of naturals n  such that  $y_k$ < $x_n$.
Example 1 -
One example of ($y_n$) would be the sequence of supremums of ($x_n$) starting from different indexes, that is,
($y_n$) =  sup{$x_1$ , $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$, ... }  ,    sup{$x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$, ... } , sup{$x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$, $x_6$, ... } , ...

Is it the only sequence with this property ?

The motivation for the question is that in my book, the lim superior of ($x_n$) was defined exactly as the infimum of a sequence with the the mentioned property ( which my book introduced, withouth explanation, as the sequence showed in Example 1 ).
 But if there are more than one sequence with the mentioned property, then lim sup in my book is not well-defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pick $y_1$ as you did, then pick $y_k > y_1$ arbitrarily for $k > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many sequences that meet your definition.  Given such a sequence, you can change $y_1$ to anything and have another.  You can change the first $m$ terms arbitrarily and have another.  If the $x_n$ are eventually bounded above, you just need all the "late" $y_n$ to be larger than that

Comment: Do you have an idea on what property uniquely defines the sequence of supremums/infimums, whose infimums and whose supremums we end up calling limit superior and limit inferior ?

Comment: The sequence you give is the definition of lim sup.  It basically is the highest value that the sequence hits (or approaches) infinitely often, so if you delete finitely many terms you will still hit it.  You can change the first $1000$ or any finite number of $x_i$ in any way you want and get the same lim sup, because you will eventually be ignoring all the changed ones.